# How to post to an controller action result method using sweet alert? mvc5 c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

Im using sweet alerts for my web application. I have come across posts with the similar problem how ever they where never answered accordingly. i want to know how would i go about posting to an action result method once the user confirms. supporting code is below . help please.

```
swal({
title: "Are you sure?",
text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
type: " warning ",
showCancelButton: true,
confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
cancelButtonText: " No, cancel plx!",
closeOnConfirm: false,
closeOnCancel: false
}, function(isConfirm) {
if (isConfirm) {
    swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
} else {
    swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe: ) ", " error ");
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you form is, but assuming it's id is form, then something like below may get you started:

```
swal({
title: "Are you sure?",
text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
type: " warning ",
showCancelButton: true,
confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
cancelButtonText: " No, cancel plx!",
closeOnConfirm: false,
closeOnCancel: false
}, function(isConfirm) {
if (isConfirm) {

// once confirm, post your form
    $("#form").submit();

} else {
    swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe: ) ", " error ");
}
});
```

Comment: thanks. i know where to put the post method, however, i am not sure what  will the post method look like..completely lost... help please?